# Covariant Derivatives: Differential Geometry

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential

Let X be the special vector field $\sum x_iU_i$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the natural coordinate functions of $R^3$. Prove that $\nabla_v$X = V for every vector field V.

I know how to compute covariant derivatives when given the vector, F, and p. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with this. Any guidance will be greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your vector field corresponds to the identity function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, thus its Jacobian matrix at any point  is the identity matrix. In your case (I suppose, since you don't provide enough informations) the covariant derivative in direction $V$ is given by the application of the jacobian matrix of the vector field to the vector $V$. So you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your response.